# How to copy a module in Magento2?

Tags: magento2.3, order-grid

I have created a new module in *`app/code/namespace/Mymodule`*. Now, I'm trying to display the information about `Custom_order` or exactly.

I want to copy module sales in *`vendor/magento/module-sales`*. I tried to research, but I can't find any guides specific to the problem I'm having.

This picture show at *namespace/sales/order/view/order_id/4/*

[image]

How can I show in another module?

Comment: Why do you want to copy module-sales in your module?

Comment: please specify your requirment into detail. what actual you are looking for?

Comment: you cant copy it but you can extend it

Comment: Thanks all. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to root > vendor > magento > module-sales
2. Download all files from this location
3. Created your module at app > code like app/code/namespace/mymodule
4. Upload all files from your storage to your newly created module's folder
5. Then run the following commands:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   ```